# How to hide a label using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Using Javascript, how do you make a label invisible on a button click?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you want but here goes:

```
<label id="mylabel">Woot!!</label>

button.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("mylabel").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just from the top of my head

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('labelname').style.display = 'none';" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A label is rendered as span tag in HTML. If you know the id of any the control you can turn off its visibility through JavaScript by

```
document.getElementById('your-element-id').style.display='none';
```